# Cython doesn't build .dll files

Tags: python, dll, cython

I am trying to build a Python extension with Cython.

My OS is `Windows7 64-bit`, with `Python2.7.5 32-bit`, `Cython 0.19.1`, and `Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1`.

I tried to follow the instruction at [this page](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/tutorial.html) to build a "Hello World" example.

I've wrote the "Hello World" Python script and "setup" file (actuall copy and paste) as the instruction told, and rename them properly.

Then I ran the `setup.py` as instructed:

> python setup.py build_ext --inplace

There are no errors or warnings in the output. However, I cannot find the `helloworld.dll` in the folder.

Where was I wrong??

Comment: Is there a `helloworld.pyd` file in the folder?

Comment: @martineau Yes, there is. Besides, there is a `build` folder as well.

Comment: The `.pyd` is your extension. Try `import helloworld` in a Python script (in the same folder) or from the Python console.

Comment: @martineau I've tried `import helloworld` with Python IDLE. But it pops an error that `ImportError: no module named helloworld`. Do I need to copy that .pyd to any specific directory?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with IDLE. In general, Python looks for modules in the current working directory, then in each directory in the list of them held in `sys.path`. One thing you can try is doing a `sys.path.append('<path_to_pyd_directory>')` before the `import helloworld` statement.

Comment: @martineau Thank you very much. It works. If you change it into an answer post, I'll accept it. Many thanks again. :)

Comment: That's good to hear. You're welcome -- but I'll pass on making it into an answer. BTW, you can answer (and accept) your own questions here on SO...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @martineau 's advice, I used `sys.path.appendsys.path.append('<path_to_pyd_directory>')` before I import my extension, and it works well.

The code I used is as follows:

> import sys
>
> sys.path.append("C:\Python27\Practice")
>
> import helloworld

The output I have is:

> Hello World

Many thanks to @martun again! :-)